# Interacting with histogram colorbars in physt polar_map

Tags: python, colorbar, polar-coordinates, histogram2d

Using the physt library you can create a polar histogram of data that automatically returns a colorbar, such as:

```
from physt.histogram_nd import Histogram2D

# Histogram2D([radian_bins, angular_bins], [histogram values for given bins])
hist = Histogram2D([[0, 0.5, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3]], [[0.2, 2.2, 7.3], [6, 5, 3]])
ax = hist.plot.polar_map(cmap = 'viridis', show_zero=False)
```

I can't link an image of this output as I don't yet have enough reputation it seems.

The colorbar is created and looks great but has no label whatsoever. Is there some keyword or arguement I can use in the polar_map function to:

1. Label my colorbar or
2. extract the colorbar object so I can use established functions such as:

```
cbar.ax.set_ylabel("colorbar name")
```

A tutorial exists (https://physt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) for this library but it doesn't really interact with the colorbar anywhere in the tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed extract the colorbar object with `ax.get_figure()`:

```
from physt.histogram_nd import Histogram2D
#
# Histogram2D([radian_bins, angular_bins], [histogram values for given bins])
hist = Histogram2D([[0, 0.5, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3]], [[0.2, 2.2, 7.3], [6, 5, 3]])
ax = hist.plot.polar_map(cmap = 'viridis', show_zero=False)
fig = ax.get_figure()
fig.axes[1].set_ylabel("colorbar name")
```

Resulting figure:
[image]